# Chrome search engine featuring "I feel lucky" broken by redirect notice

Tags: google-chrome

For years, my most-used chrome feature has been one that I configured:  I call it "Luckypedia", marrying the power of Google search with Wikipedia content.

I manually added a search engine in Chrome with the keyword "lp" and the url `http://www.google.com/search?q=%s%20site%3Aen.wikipedia.org&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&meta=`.

This allowed me to type "lp dark strings" into the chrome address field, and chrome would show me the wikipedia entry that google feels is most associated with the term "dark strings".

Life was wonderful.

But recently, this functionality has been degraded because Google started displaying a "redirect notice" for URLs including the "I'm feeling lucky" btnI parameter.

Any recommendations on how to re-enable this functionality and avoid the redirect notice?

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same boat and yet to find a way to avoid the redirect notice (without installing additional extensions)

For now switching my custom search engines to **use duckduckgo** *"im feeling lucky"* bang is good enough for me:

```
#Use the ! bang for ifl functionality
Generic: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!+%s

#Use the !w bang for wikipedia site results only
Wikipedia: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!+!w+%s

#Or use site: functionality to limit results
Wikipedia: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!+site:en.wikipedia.org+%s
```

List of !bangs: https://duckduckgo.com/bang?q=wikipedia
 
Google Thread: https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/15794018